# How to save data in related table in Laravel using lazy relations?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have two table: `users, users_parameters`.

Relation is as: `users.id = users_parameters.user_id`

In model `User` I have:

```
public function parameters()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\UserParameters', 'user_id');
    }
```

I tried to add new user like as:

```
$user = new User();
$user->password = "123";
$user->email = "user@example.com";

$user->parameters()->name = $request->name;
$user->save(); // or ->push();
```

It does not work, dont add new user to realated tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$user = new User();
$user->password = "123";
$user->email = "user@mail.ru";
$user->save();

$parameter = new Parameter();
$parameter->name = $request->name;
$parameter->save();

$user->parameters()->save($parameter);
```

[Here's an explanation.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models)

Or using [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#mass-assignment):

```
$user = User::create(['name' => '123', 'email' => 'user@mail.ru']);
$user->parameters()->create(['name' => $request->name]);
```